# syste.loadlibrary()/system.load() fails to load a library (.so) file

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries

system.loadlibrary() and system.load() fails to load the .so file I have created but successfully loads other already present lib.so files.

I am creating the lib file with following command:
gcc -o .so  -shared -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/include -I/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/include/linux -I/usr/local/include/test -ltest -lrt -lpthread

here the library calls some functions from a testlib.so, hence included test directory as well..

is there anything I am missing or doing wrong while creating the library??

Comment: What happens when you call `System.loadLibrary(fullPathToSO)`? Does it throw an error? Remember that `System.loadLibrary()` requires the full path to the library while `System.load()` checks for a library with that name in some predetermined locations...

Comment: Believe you have those swapped

Comment: Thanks a ton guys, I just rebuilt the library again and it loaded successfully. it must have been some linking issue. Thanks again..!!